# Program for Project Euler Problem 15 only works for digits less than 12

Tags: python

[Project Euler Problem 15](https://projecteuler.net/problem=15)

Starting in the top left corner of a 2×2 grid, there are 6 routes (without backtracking) to the bottom right corner.
How many routes are there through a 20×20 grid?

Start from the bottom right and go up by adding top and left numbers

```
table = {}
table["01"] = 1
table["10"] = 1 

def find_cost(x, y):
    top_pos = str(x) + str(y - 1)
    left_pos = str(x - 1) + str(y)
    current_pos = str(x) + str(y)
    if top_pos in table and left_pos in table:  # if it's in a table then add it
        table[current_pos] = table[left_pos] + table[top_pos]
        return table[current_pos]
    elif x == 1: # if the leftmost, then add 1 in a table
        table[left_pos] = 1
        table[current_pos] = 1 + find_cost(x, y - 1)
        return table[current_pos]
    elif y == 1: # the same for y
        table[top_pos] = 1
        table[current_pos] = 1 + table[left_pos]
        return table[current_pos]
    else: # if I don't have anything, then call it for left and top 
        table[current_pos] = find_cost(x - 1, y) + find_cost(x, y - 1)
        return table[current_pos]
```

Comment: What happens if it does "not work"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hint: to which cell corresponds `table["123"]`? To `x = 1` and `y = 23` or `x = 12` and `y = 3`?

You need to be able to identify cells uniquely from the key of the `table`. So try to construct the key with a separator, for example:

```
top_pos = str(x) + ":" + str(y - 1)
left_pos = str(x - 1) + ":" + str(y)
current_pos = str(x) + ":" + str(y)
```

and initialize it like

```
table["0:1"] = 1
table["1:0"] = 1
```